# How to fix a while loop that is not functioning correctly in Python

Tags: python, while-loop

So im writing a prorgram that calculates the mpg a user inputs, but my while loop is not working. Here's what i got so far:

```
#This program calculates miles per gallon the user enter
totalMPG = 0.0

#Ask user for the gallons used
gallons = input ('Enter gallons used(-1 to end): ')
#convert gallons to int
gallons = float(gallons)
#Ask user for the miles driven 
miles_driven = input("Enter the miles driven: ")
#convert miles to a float number
miles_driven = float(miles_driven)


# calculate miles/gallon and round 
mpg = miles_driven / gallons
mpg = round(mpg,2)

#print out mpg
print('Your miles per gallon is: ', mpg)


#while gallons does not equal -1
while gallons != "-1":

   mpg_value = float(mpg)
   totalMPG += mpg_value
   gallons = input("Enter gallons used (-1 to end): ")
   miles_driven = input("Enter the miles driven: ")
   print ('Your miles per gallon is: ', mpg)

print("Your total miles per gallons is: ", totalMPG)

avg = totalMPG / mpg
print ("You're average miles per gallons is ", avg)
```

when i enter -1 to exit the program, it just goes straight to asking to enter the miles.

Comment: Is this Python 2 or 3?

Comment: you can change your while to `while True:` and add an if condition `if gallons == -1: break`, assuming that you are coding in `python3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`while gallons != "-1":` doesn't mean that as soon as `gallons` becomes `"-1"` the loop will exit. The condition is only checked at the start of each iteration.

If you want to do the check after `gallons` is assigned, you need to manually handle that:

```
while True:

   mpg_value = float(mpg)
   totalMPG += mpg_value
   gallons = input("Enter gallons used (-1 to end): ")

   if gallons == "-1":  # Tell it to break from the loop here
       break

   miles_driven = input("Enter the miles driven: ")
   print ('Your miles per gallon is: ', mpg)
```

Comment: So it worked! It stops once i enter -1 but another issue is that when it asks me to enter the second input for the gallons and miles it gives me the same calculation as the first mpg.

Comment: @RMGonza You're calculating `mpg` only once before the loop. `mpg` won't automatically update itself when `gallons` changes. If you want `mpg` to change, you have to manually reassign it again.

Answer (score 2):

```
gallons = float(gallons)
...
while gallons != "-1":
```

Your converted input is `float`; you compared against a string.  These can never be equal.  Use one or the other.

Within the loop, you've kept `gallons` as a string.  However, you ask for `miles` before you loop back to check the value of `gallons` and exit the loop.  In short, your loop exit logic is out of order: you need the `gallons` input at the *bottom* of the loop.

Comment: Granted, but the specific question is why the program goes *straight* to asking for miles, even when the input is -1.  However, it does warrant clarification.

Answer (score 0):

> It's better to use `while True` and `break some_condition` expression.

**Debug:**

```
print(type(gallons)) # output: int
```

So `gallons` never be `"-1"`

**Code:**

```py
# python3.x
# This program calculates miles per gallon the user enter

def calculate_mpg():
    _GET_GALLONS_MSG = "Enter gallons used (-1 to end): "
    _GET_MILES_DRIVEN_MSG = "Enter the miles driven: "
    _MPG_FINAL_MSG = "Your miles per gallon is: "
    _MPG_AVG_MSG = "You're average miles per gallons is "

    total_mpg, counter = 0.0, 0

    while True:

        try:
            gallons = float(input(_GET_GALLONS_MSG))

            if gallons == -1:
                break
            miles_driven = float(input(_GET_MILES_DRIVEN_MSG))

            total_mpg += round(gallons/miles_driven, 2)
            counter += 1

        except ValueError as e:
            print(e)

    avg_mpg = total_mpg / counter

    print(_MPG_FINAL_MSG, total_mpg)
    print(_MPG_AVG_MSG, avg_mpg)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    calculate_mpg()
```